# How the listview content horizontally without looking over flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need to show the listview content horizontally without looking over it. I maintain that the substance should be on a new line when the width is full. how might I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `Wrap`, use it with a `SingleChildScrollView` like so:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Wrap(
    children: [
      // your children.
    ]
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aspect ratio` to make a horizontally listview.
An example starting code;

```html
  Widget buildCard({
    required CardItem item,
  }) =>
      Container(
        width: 200,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
                ...
```